# Mysql join for the following ER

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following table structure of my db:

- tbl_project
- tbl_employee
- tbl_deliverable
- user_to_deliverable

Where **tbl_prjct** and **tbl_deliverable** have a *1-to-many* relationship, 
**tbl_employee** and **tbl_deliverable** have *many-many* relationships so they are split into **user_to_deliverable** table.

I want a query to show project_name(from tbl_project), project's deliverables (from tbl_deliverable) and employee name which that specific deliverable is assigned to.

Can I get help writing this query?

Comment: much better if you can include the schema of each table.

Comment: @JohnWoo not just much better, I think more of a basic requirement.

Comment: One minus many... haven't heard of that relation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired query is much like 89.67% like this :D

```
SELECT      a.ProjectName,
            b.deliverables,
            d.employeename
FROM        tbl_project a
                INNER JOIN tbl_deliverable b
                    ON a.projectID = b.projectID
                INNER JOIN user_to_deliverable c
                    ON b.recordID = c.RecordID      
                        -- or could be the primary key
                INNER JOIN tbl_employee d
                    ON c.userID = d.userID
```

Comment: @baig772 i mean it's the `ID` that links `user_to_deliverable` with `tbl_deliverable`. by the way, the specified `ID`s on the query are the linking `IDs`

Answer (score 0):

Approximate solution without knowing your schema.  If you want the deliverables/employees concatenated for each project it would probably be best done by retrieving the results and parsing in a non-SQL language (PHP, Python, or whatever you are using).  If you want this completely done in SQL you will need to use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
select tbl_project.name as project,
       tbl_deliverable.name as deliverable,
       tbl_employee.name as employee
from tbl_project
join tbl_deliverable
    on (tbl_project.id = tbl_deliverable.project_id)
join user_to_deliverable
    on (tbl_deliverable.id = user_to_deliverable.deliverable_id)
join tbl_employee
    on (user_to_deliverable.employee_id = tbl_employee.id)
```